# "All" constraint satisfied, by ...?

Tags: logic

I'm looking for a way to express that an "all" constraint is satisfied, because there are no items to speak of.  An example might be clear here:

```
Let a set of numbers be called "all-odd" if EACH of its items is odd.
The sets, {3, 5, 7}, {1}, and {9, 13} are all-odd.  
Note that the empty set { } is also all-odd because of __your answer here__.
```

**EDIT:**

The answer I was looking for is in the comments:

```
Note that the empty set { } is vacuously all-odd.
```

Comment: Take a look at the idea of a vacuous truth, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth. Not only are all the items in that set odd, they're also all even.

Comment: In fact, every item in the set is anything you want it to be.

Comment: As @ymbirtt said: you'd write "Note that the empty set is also (vacuously) all-odd."

Comment: This sounds like you are expected to use a term you learned in class. As @ymbirtt said, the term "vacuously truth" is usually used, but that doesn't seem to fit the sentence here. I would write that as "... is also all-odd because it is vacuously true."   But "vacuous truth" might fit - it seems grammatically odd to me.

Comment: @ymbirtt This is the answer I was looking for.  If you make it into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually, Trevor's pretty much summed up the idea behind vacuous proof in his answer.

Comment: @ymbirtt It sounds like the OP just wanted to know the terminology that applies to this situation, so your comment would be the better answer.

Comment: @TrevorWilson: Correct.  btw thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple example of a vacuous truth, and all the details you need are on Wikipedia at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth. In essence, since $\bot \implies x$ for any logical statement $x$, it is correct to say that the elements of the empty set all have any particular property.

All the elements of the empty set are odd. This statement is vacuously true.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that every element $x$ of a set $S$ has property $P$, we let $x$ be an element of $S$ and then prove that $x$ has property $P$.

So let $x \in \emptyset$.  Then $\emptyset$ is not empty, a contradiction.  Therefore $x$ is odd (because anything follows from a contradiction.)  We then conclude $\forall x \in \emptyset\,P(x)$, where $P$ is the property of being odd.

As copper.hat pointed out in the comments, the same argument works for any property $P$.

Comment: I wasn't trying to prove the result.  I was trying to communicate why the result holds.  The expression "vacuous truth" is what I was looking for.

Comment: @CSJ Oh, I see. You might want to ask ymbirtt to make his/her comment into an answer so that you can accept it.